# Working with mysql inside of php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with php and mysql. 
I am having issues with something I am trying to accomplish. 
Basically I want to check to see if there are 3 or more records containing a given date when a form is submitted. 
I want to insert the new record from the form. (This is working)
And then check the table to see if the time occurs 3 or more times with the date from the form. If it does, I want to create an entry into a different table which holds blocked times so that they are not accessible. The form reads from the second table to populate a drop down list of times that are allowed. 
I'm not positive how I should go about this.

This is the code I am using for the insert:

```
try 
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO logTable (logDate, logTime, logProgram, logInterest) VALUES (:date,:time,:program,:interest)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':date' => $newDate, ':time' => $formData->tour_time, ':program' => $formData->program, ':interest' => $formData->selected_interests));

}
 catch(PDOException $ex) 
{
    echo "Cannot connect to the database, please try again at a later time.";
}
```

That code works for inserting

I need to check logTable for any times that occur three or more times on the same date

This is how I was trying to do this but it is not working:

```
$originalDate = $formData->tour_date;
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($originalDate));
$thisTime = $formData->log_time
$response = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logTable WHERE logDate = $newDate AND logTime = $thisTime");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($response);

if($num_rows > 2)
{
     $query2 = "INSERT into blockedTimes (blockedDate, blockedTime) VALUES ($newDate, $thisTime)";
if(mysql_query == false)
{
    $aryResponse = array('status' => 'error', 'error'=>'Could not connect to the database. ');
    ob_clean();
    print json_encode($aryResponse);
    exit();
}
}
```

I can not figure out why this is not working. Please help.

Comment: You need to use parameters.

Comment: Sidenote. Missing ending semi-colon in `$thisTime = $formData->log_time`

Comment: Is there some reason your are mixing what seems to be like PDO and mysql_* calls? Stick with just PDO.

Comment: Plus, since you're dealing with strings, this `AND logTime = $thisTime` and this `VALUES ($newDate, $thisTime)` should be wrapped in quotes. `AND logTime = '$thisTime'` and `VALUES ('$newDate', '$thisTime')` - Modify those and try it again.

Comment: The problem with your `SELECT` query is that you forgot to quote the date. But if you use PDO and a parametrized query, that won't be a problem.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would go about using just PDO to accomplish this? I am pretty new to php so I have been going with some other code I have seen and been able to make work on other things. @Chris